# vuejs undefined value when switching template

Tags: vue.js

I'm porting a list to a table to further expand out the columns in the future, but I'm running into an undefined variable error, which I don't understand.

Here's the existing list:

```
                <ul class="collection with-header">
                    <li class="collection-item" v-for="day in days">
                        <drop @drop="function(data, event) { handleDrop(data, day, event); }">
                            <div>{{ day.getLabel() }}</div>
                            <drag class="chip" v-for="meal in day.meals">{{ meal.title }}<i class="close material-icons" v-on:click="deleteMeal(meal)">close</i></drag>
                        </drop>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

And here's the new table:

```
                <table>
                    <tr class="collection-item" v-for="day in days">
                        <td>{{ day.getLabel() }}</td>
                        <drop @drop="function(data, event) { handleDrop(data, day, event); }" tag="td">
                            <drag class="chip" v-for="meal in day.meals">{{ meal.title }}<i class="close material-icons" v-on:click="deleteMeal(meal)">close</i></drag>
                        </drop>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

When running the code, I get a "day is not defined" error, which seems to occur on the *drag* line as commenting it out fixes the error.  What I don't understand is why that variable isn't defined.  In both an element has access to the *day* object to get its label, but in the drop tag, which is identical in both examples, the day object is now out of scope.

Is there something about tables specifically that is causing a problem here?

Comment: add your script file too

Comment: What is the default / initial value for `days`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the replacement of the `component` tag with the tag passed to it in the props occurs after the template is transformed into DOM. And in the case of a table, tags that are not allowed to be inside the table are transferred to the DOM before the table:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 4px solid green;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First column</td>
      <component :is="'td'" tag="td">Second column</component>
      <td>Third column</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And, accordingly, there will be no variable `day` in `tr` scope. So do not use in this case the attribute `tag`:

```
  <table>
    <tr class="collection-item" v-for="day in days">
      <td>{{ day.label }}</td>
      <td>
        <drop @drop="function(data, event) { handleDrop(data, day, event); }">
          <drag class="chip" v-for="meal in day.meals">{{ meal.title }}
              <i class="close material-icons" v-on:click="deleteMeal(meal)">x</i>
          </drag>
        </drop>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer.  I want to better understand the mechanism for moving this out of the table, but this points me in the right direction as the code is now doing what I expect.